# How to add multiple lines without wiping the whole page?

Tags: html

I would like to print out the ":::" multiple times. However, using this code, I can only print the last line. How can I print all of these lines?

```
<body>
    <script>

        function tri(){
            var radius;

            radius = parseInt(document.getElementById("r").value);

            for (var i = 0; i < radius; i++){
                for (var j = 0; j < i; j++){
                    document.getElementById("triOut").innerHTML = ":::";
                }
                document.getElementById("triOut").innerHTML = "<br>";
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < radius; i++){
                for(var j = 0; j < radius-i; j++){
                    document.getElementById("triOut").innerHTML = ":::";
                }
                document.getElementById("triOut").innerHTML = "<br>";
            }

        }

    </script>


    Give me a number <input type="text" id="r"><button onclick="tri()"> Click here! </button>
    <p id="triOut"></p>

</body>
```

I expect something like

```
:::
::::::
:::::::::
::::::
:::
```

Instead, I got nothing shown on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loops you overwrite the output when repeatedly using `=`. You want to concatenate with `+=`

```js
function tri() {
  var radius;

  radius = parseInt(document.getElementById("r").value);

  for (var i = 0; i < radius; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      document.getElementById("triOut").innerHTML += ":::";
    }
    document.getElementById("triOut").innerHTML += "<br>";
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < radius; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < radius - i; j++) {
      document.getElementById("triOut").innerHTML += ":::";
    }
    document.getElementById("triOut").innerHTML += "<br>";
  }

}
```

```html
Give me a number <input type="text" id="r"><button onclick="tri()"> Click here! </button>
<p id="triOut"></p>
```